# Charges inside a coonducting sphere and $E$-field

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, gauss-law, conductors

After reading the title most people will think this is a well known duplicate, however, i do have a strange question i couldn't find an answer for after going through a few of these duplicates.

[image]

Consider the sphere in the picture. Goal is to calculate E-field at the different positions. What i understood about conductors and charges: a charge inside a spherical cavity will induce the same charge right at the surface of the conductor wall: situation looks like this

[image]

The charges drawn are basically fixed in place. So i assume the E-field at $x_0$ is $0$ (either i draw a gaussian circle small enough to only cover the point of $x_0$ or add up the charges vectorially, since $x_0$ is in between the two hollowed cavities, E should be 0). At $x_1$, is where i'm very unsure. If i draw a gaussian surface with radius being from $x_0$ to $x_1$ then the total charge is $0$ and i say at $x_1$ the E-field is $0$. But then if i simply add them up vectorially, because of the distance of the charges to the point in question, E cannot be $0$. And use gauss's law again i would say $x_2$ is $0$ because the total charge enclosed is $0$.

Can someone point out where my understanding or reasoning is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gauss is limited in that all it can tell you is the **total** flux passing through the surface of a volume which contains charge.
To find the actual electric field at points on the surface is not possible except for special cases like those with spherical symmetry.

One thing that you do know is that if this is a static situation the electric field inside a conductor is zero.

The simplest case is for the two charges to be of equal magnitude and at the centre of the cavities.
Think of it in terms of field lines which was how Gauss came about.
They start on positive charges and end on negative charges.  So the magnitude of induced charges on the surface of the cavity must be the same as the magnitude of the charge at the centre of the cavity and by symmetry the surface charge density is the same.
That's it, all the charges are accounted for and to the world outside the cavities all that is seen is a region with a net zero charge.

If the two charges are not at the centre of the cavities then that will disturb the uniformity of the surface induced charge densities but again all charges are accounted for.

If the magnitudes of the two charges are not equal then there will be a net induced charge resident uniformly on the outer surface of the conductor so to the world outside the conductor it is as though that net induced charge is resident at the centre of the conductor.
The induced charge on the surface of the cavities will in magnitude be equal to the charges within the cavities and again there will be no electric field within the conductor.

Thus you are very limited to the use of Gauss (charges at centre of cavity, spherical conductor etc) and can find out about the electric field at some positions but in theory you would have to use Coulomb's law and/or other methods based on energy to find the charge distributions and electric fields and I guess the resulting horrible integrals would have to be evaluated numerically?

Comment: Hi thank you very much for this. This answers the question of my confusion. I just have a follow up question, you said that if the charges are at the center of the cavity(which they are) then to the outside world (in this case at $x_2$) it should be a region of 0 charge. But if i add up all the charges vectorially, it isn't 0right? The total charge might be 0 but we could still calculate the dipole ? And no i don't have to calculate the integral, just analytical reasoning would be enough, the question asks me which region has 0 E-field and which region has the maximum E-field

Comment: Going back to field lines starting on positive charges and ending on negative charges.  The magnitude of the induced charges on the surface of a cavity is equal to the magnitude of the charge inside the cavity.  That is, every field line which starts on a positive charges ends on a negative charge so there are no more “spare” field lines to interact outside the cavities and indeed there can be no field lines inside the conductor.

Answer (score 1):

If the points are present inside the bulk of conductor, then electric field at those points has to be zero due to high permittivity of metals. All the charges inside the bulk travels and reside at the surface of conductor to minimize repulsion. If the magnitude of charges is equal and opposite, then net charges density is zero.
So electric field at all points is zero and can be verified using gauss's law.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just draw a guassian surface whereever you feel like it to get the E field. Remember the guassian surface tells you the charge inside is equal to the area integral of the field projected on the surface.

There needs to be spherical symmetry inside your guassian surface; if there's not, redraw it.

For $x_0$, you wouldn't use guass' law so much as just take the vector sum (as you noted).

To be safe, for $x_1$ you should take 2 gaussian surfaces - one with the center on $-q$ and the other with the center on $+q$, then add the fields you get from each. Taking a gaussian sphere centered on $x_0$ doesn't guarantee the right answer (though it will be correct, incidentally) because the volume is no longer spherically symmetric.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you cannot use the Gauss theorem for points $x_0$ and $x_1$ here, because you do not take into consideration the free charges and their distribution in the conducting sphere. Here it is better to use the method of imaginary charges, where instead of small charged spheres there are point charges of identical value. For the point $x_2$ we can apply the Gauss theorem, since the sum of free charges inside the sphere is $0$.